# RMI - Unmarshalled Exception

Tags: java, rmi, unmarshalling

I can't seem to get this working. I'm just look at it for basic instruction for a lab, but I've no experience with RMI at all. I can't seem to get why I'm getting the error.

Server

```
    public static void runServer() {
        // Install security manager, if none is present
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            System.out.println("Reg: " + registry.toString());
            String name = "Server";
            Server server = new Server();
            I_Server stub = (I_Server) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);

            registry.rebind(name, stub);
            System.out.println("All is well :-)\n");
        } catch (RemoteException re) {
            System.err.println("Remote Exception in DisplayGetEngine.main()\n");
            re.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I have the following run commands and arguments in NetBeans

Arguments: -cp C:\rmi\Server\src;C:\rmi\Server\dist\Server.jar -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/C:/rmi/Server/dist/Server.jar

Working Directory: C:\rmi\Server

My stacktrace is, at the rebind method.

```
Reg: RegistryImpl_Stub[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.50.18.205:1099](remote),objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]]
Remote Exception in DisplayGetEngine.main()

java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: server.I_Server
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at server.Server.runServer(Server.java:50)
    at server.Server.main(Server.java:31)
```

If I don't run rmiregistry, this is my stacktrace

Remote Exception in DisplayGetEngine.main()

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.50.18.205; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at server.Server.runServer(Server.java:50)
    at server.Server.main(Server.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `createRegistry()` first to make sure that you have a running registry. Also, port 0 should be a reserved port so you won't be able to make your server listen on that particular port. Try the default one 1099.

Comment: That's helped somewhat! I'm getting a java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table exception now!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://osdir.com/ml/java.sun.rmi/2005-09/msg00005.html) post. Seems like you run into this bug. You can either try running ````getRegistry```` after ````createRegistry```` and invoke the rebind on the object returned from ````getRegistry````, or try invoking ````Naming.rebind()````.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in running `rmiregistry`. If you look into the stacktrace closely,the problem seems to be `ClassNotFoundException` while the arguments are being unmarshalled in the rmi registry. You will have to check the code base of the RMI server whether `server.I_Server` class is present in the Server.jar while running it in the classpath.

From RMI FAQs

> A.4 Why am I getting a ClassNotFoundException?
>   Most likely the java.rmi.server.codebase property has not been set (or has not been set correctly) on a VM that is exporting your remote object(s). Please take a look at our tutorial, [Dynamic code downloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html) using Java RMI (Using the java.rmi.server.codebase Property).

Comment: The arguments are being un marshalled in the Registry, not in the RMI server. (The Registry is another RMI server.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the build file. I needed to insert this statement.

```
<target name="startRMI" depends="init">
<exec executable="C:\Program\Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\rmiregistry"
dir="${build.classes.dir}"></exec>
</target>
```